# Why is translation symmetry an important recipe in performing a Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, spin-chains

In page 3 of Vodola's dissertation, [Correlations and Quantum Dynamics of 1D Fermionic Models: New Results for the Kitaev Chain with Long-Range Pairing](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01303734/document), it was stated that assuming translation symmetry of a closed ring allows him to perform a Fourier transform in the Hamiltonian. **Why is translation symmetry an important recipe in performing a Fourier transform?** I understand that after performing the Fourier transform, one can write the Hamiltonian into a block-diagonal form. From there, one can set a new fermionic field using Bogoliubov transformations. And, eventually, the Hamiltonian can be diagonalized. **Also, can someone help me understand the importance of performing first the Fourier transform before diagonalizing the Hamiltonian?**

Comment: With translation symmetry,  the fourier transform is useful and makes diagonalizing easy. Without that symmetry you can still do the fourier transform, but it may not make diagonalizing any easier.

Comment: Yeah, it could be. Even in the [diagonalization of XY model Hamiltonian by V. Ohanyan](http://training.hepi.edu.ge/rtn/activities/sources/Ohanyan.pdf) , the translation symmetry was also mentioned. But I still don't understand how it affects the calculation since the assumption appears only before perfoming the Fourier transform.

Comment: It's not an assumption. It's a motivation.